# I use the slides documentclass with the landscape option. How can vertically top align each slide without using beamer?

Tags: formatting, vertical-alignment

When I compile the code below, the first line of each slide is not at the same distance from the top. I would like the first line of each slide to be at the same distance (vertically top aligned). I prefer not to use beamer.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{slides}
\begin{document}

First slide first line

First slide second line

\newpage

Second slide first line

Second slide second line

Second slide third line

\end{document}
```

Comment: If the `slides` class is appropriate than you can't use Beamer because you aren't making those kinds of slides. Conversely, if Beamer would be appropriate, you can't use `slides` for slides of the kind you need. Are you creating overhead transparencies? If so, `slides` will do it. If you are creating slides for LCD projection, however, `slides` is absolutely not what you want here.

Comment: If you are making overheads, you probably want to use the `slide` environment.

Comment: @cfr, i vote for be duplicate by mistake. i already retract my wrong voting.

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly, but it works.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{slides}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
First slide first line

First slide second line
\end{minipage}\newpage
\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
Second slide first line

Second slide second line

Second slide third line
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```